# Problema con .change de javascript (toma el dato previo seleccionado)

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax

tengo un formulario:

[image: formulario]

En donde tengo un select de proveedor que me trae el porcentaje de retención que les pertenece al seleccionarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$(".js-proveedor-id").on('change', function() {

        var proveedor_id = $("#proveedor_id");

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('get_proveedor_by_id') }}",
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                proveedor_id: proveedor_id.val(),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#retencion").val(data.retencion);
                retencion = data.retencion;
        }
        
    });

        totales(retencion);
    });
```

Ahora, mi intención es que cada que se cambie la opción del select, este me traiga el valor del % de retención y me vuelva a realizar todos los cálculos de la factura; pero por alguna razón no me está tomando el cambio del valor de la retención sino hasta que vuelvo a cambiar el select.

Por ejemplo: yo selecciono un proveedor con 100% de retención y agrego los artículos que quiera y todo funciona, pero si deseo cambiar el proveedor y selecciono uno con 0% no me realiza ningún cambio sino hasta que vuelvo a seleccionar otro y me refleja el cálculo con el 0% de retención; es decir que se está quedando con el valor seleccionado anteriormente.

Si yo agrego otro artículo luego de seleccionar otro proveedor sí me actualiza la retención; pero al cambiarla o eliminar algún artículo no.

Mi función de `totales()`

```
function totales() {

        retencion = $("#retencion").val();

        $("#subtotal").html("$ " + subtotalapagar.toFixed(2));
        subtotal_pagar = subtotalapagar;
        $("#subtotal_pagar_html").html("$ " + subtotal_pagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#subtotal_pagar").val(subtotal_pagar.toFixed(2));

        impuesto = subtotalapagar * 0.16;
        $("#impuesto").html("$ " + impuesto.toFixed(2));
        impuesto_pagar = impuesto;
        $("#impuesto_pagar_html").html("$ " + impuesto_pagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#impuesto_pagar").val(impuesto_pagar.toFixed(2));


        retencionapagar = impuesto_pagar * (retencion / 100);
        $("#retencion").html("$ " + retencionapagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#retencion_pagar_html").html("$ " + retencionapagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#retencion_pagar").val(retencionapagar.toFixed(2));

        total_pagar = subtotalapagar + impuesto_pagar - retencionapagar;

        $("#total").html("$ " + total_pagar.toFixed(2));

        $("#total_pagar_html").html("$ " + total_pagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_pagar").val(total_pagar.toFixed(2));

        tasa = $("#tasabs").val();

        total_pagarbs = tasa * total_pagar;

        $("#totalbs").html("Bs. " + total_pagarbs.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_pagar_htmlbs").html("Bs. " + total_pagarbs.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_pagarbs").val(total_pagarbs.toFixed(2));
    }
```

Y la de eliminar:

```
function eliminar(index) {
        retencion = $("#retencion").val();

        subtotalapagar = subtotalapagar - subtotal[index];
        impuesto = subtotalapagar * 0.16;

        retencionapagar = impuesto * (retencion / 100);

        total = subtotalapagar + impuesto - retencionapagar;
        total_pagar_html = total;

        $("#impuesto").html("$ " + impuesto.toFixed(2));
        impuesto_pagar = impuesto;
        $("#impuesto_pagar_html").html("$ " + impuesto_pagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#impuesto_pagar").val(impuesto_pagar.toFixed(2));

        
        $("#retencion").html("$ " + retencionapagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#retencion_pagar_html").html("$ " + retencionapagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#retencion_pagar").val(retencionapagar.toFixed(2));

        subtotal_pagar = subtotalapagar;
        $("#subtotal").html("$ " + subtotalapagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#subtotal_pagar_html").html("$ " + subtotal_pagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#subtotal_pagar").val(subtotal_pagar.toFixed(2));

        $("#total").html("$ " + total);
        $("#total_pagar_html").html("$ " + total_pagar_html.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_pagar").val(total_pagar_html.toFixed(2));

        total_pagarbs = tasa * total;
        $("#totalbs").html("Bs. " + total_pagarbs.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_pagar_htmlbs").html("Bs. " + total_pagarbs.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_pagarbs").val(total_pagarbs.toFixed(2));

        $("#fila" + index).remove();
        evaluar();
    }
```

Comment: Intenta agregando **On** que ayuda a gestionar la funcionalidad de eventos, **$(".js-proveedor-id").on('change', function() {**.

Comment: @AntonioGalicia cambié eso pero de igual forma no me funciona, sigue tomando el valor anterior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el error puede estar en la función **click**, ya que debes obtener el **value** antes de entrar a la petición y no lo hacías modificala y me dices si funciona, ejemplo:

```js
$(".js-proveedor-id").on("change", function () {
  var proveedor_value = $("#proveedor_id").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('get_proveedor_by_id') }}",
    method: "GET",
    data: {
      proveedor_value: proveedor_value
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $("#retencion").val(data.retencion);
    }
  });

  //totales(proveedor_value);
  
  //COMPROBAMOS QUE OBTENGA EL ID DEL SELECT
  alert('Value del select clickeado: '+proveedor_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="proveedor_id">Proveedor</label>
<select class="form-control selectpicker proveedorB js-proveedor-id" data-live-search="true" name="proveedor_id" id="proveedor_id" lang="es" autofocus required>
  <option value="1">Proveedor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Proveedor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Proveedor 3</option>
</select>
```

En la función **totales**:

```js
function totales(retencion) {

  $("#subtotal").html("$ " + subtotalapagar.toFixed(2));
  subtotal_pagar = subtotalapagar;
  $("#subtotal_pagar_html").html("$ " + subtotal_pagar.toFixed(2));
  $("#subtotal_pagar").val(subtotal_pagar.toFixed(2));

  impuesto = subtotalapagar * 0.16;
  $("#impuesto").html("$ " + impuesto.toFixed(2));
  impuesto_pagar = impuesto;
  $("#impuesto_pagar_html").html("$ " + impuesto_pagar.toFixed(2));
  $("#impuesto_pagar").val(impuesto_pagar.toFixed(2));


  retencionapagar = impuesto_pagar * (retencion / 100);
  $("#retencion").html("$ " + retencionapagar.toFixed(2));
  $("#retencion_pagar_html").html("$ " + retencionapagar.toFixed(2));
  $("#retencion_pagar").val(retencionapagar.toFixed(2));

  total_pagar = subtotalapagar + impuesto_pagar - retencionapagar;

  $("#total").html("$ " + total_pagar.toFixed(2));

  $("#total_pagar_html").html("$ " + total_pagar.toFixed(2));
  $("#total_pagar").val(total_pagar.toFixed(2));

  tasa = $("#tasabs").val();

  total_pagarbs = tasa * total_pagar;

  $("#totalbs").html("Bs. " + total_pagarbs.toFixed(2));
  $("#total_pagar_htmlbs").html("Bs. " + total_pagarbs.toFixed(2));
  $("#total_pagarbs").val(total_pagarbs.toFixed(2));
}
```

Recibimos el parámetro como **retencion** y ya no tomamos el *value con jquery*. Inténtalo así y me dices, es un poco complejo replicar sin la data que obtienes.

Comment: es que el problema no es el id del proveedor, porque yo tengo una parte en el formulario donde muestra el % de retención, y ese número sí me lo trae, el problema es a la hora del cálculo, que es como si no me cambiara el valor de la retención sino hasta que se vuelve a hacer la función, y entonces me toma el anterior seleccionado; pero en el input donde lo escribe sí lo cambia.

Comment: Ok, entendí mal entonces, y como tal el id no es lo importante si no el **value**, al ejecutar la función **totales()** pasale como parámetro el value obtenido por el click, ejemplo **totales(proveedor_id );** y con eso deberia tomar el valor correcto, edito mi respuesta y me dices.

Comment: de igual forma no me realiza la función de totales sino hasta que vuelvo a cambiarla, y con la retención anterior. ¿tendrá algo que ver el dónde se encuentra el ``totales()`` dentro de la función¿?

Comment: Supongo, hay algún detalle que estamos omitiendo, si puedes editar tu pregunta solo dejando los bloques de código donde se encuentra el problema, los que ya funcionan omitelos, y explica detalladamente que quieres que haga y donde falla, haber si comprendemos mejor.

Comment: Que te arroja la **data** del succes de Ajax?

Comment: ahí actualicé la pregunta. La data me trae los datos de ese proveedor, (id, razon_social, retencion, etc), ¿agrego la función que tengo en el controlador para que la puedas visualizar? si le doy ``alert(data. -dato que yo quiera ver-)`` me arroja el dato, por ejemplo ``alert(data.retencion)`` me trae la retención de ese proveedor

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es por qué si me cambia el valor del input dentro del formulario pero no me toma ese mismo valor dentro de la función ``totales()``

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139202/discussion-between-antonio-galicia-and-karelix-alejandra).

Comment: ya lo arreglé, moviendo el ``totales()`` dentro del ``success``